# How to delete row n and n+1 in a dataframe?

Tags: r, row, dataframe

I have several dataframes in which I want to delete each row that matches a certain string. I used the following code to do it:

```
 df[!(regexpr("abc", df$V4) ==1),]
```

How can I delete the row that is following, e.g. if I delete row n as specified by the code above, how can I additionally delete row n+1?

My first try was to simply find out the indices of the desired rows, but that won't work, as I need to delete rows in different dataframes which are of different lengths. So the indices vary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use which() on your logical expression and then you can just add 1 to the result.

```
sel <- which(grep("abc", df$V4))
sel <- c(sel, sel+1)
df[-sel,]
```

Comment: So, with help from a friend, I ended up with this code, which is basically what you suggested:  `del <- c(which(regexpr("abc", df$V4) ==1),(which(regexpr("abc", df$V4) ==1)+1))
 df2 <- df[-del,]`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking out and manipulating the logical vector directly. Suppose we have the vector:

```
x = c(5,0,1, 4, 3)
```

and we want to do:

```
x[x > 3]
```

First, note that:

```
R> (s_n = x>3)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So

```
R> (s_n1 = as.logical(s_n + c(F, l[1:(length(s_n)-1)])))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Hence,

```
x[s_n1]
```

gives you what you want.

---

In your particular example, something like:

```
s_n = !(regexpr("abc", df$V4) == 1)
s_n1 = as.logical(s_n + c(F, l[1:(length(s_n)-1)])))
df[s_n1, ]
```

should work.

Comment: 1+ Agree with the logic, but readability would be improved if you used a different symbol for your logical vector. Solitary letter `l` is much too similar to `1` at least in the font used on my browser above.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[which(!(regexpr("abc", df$V4) ==1))+c(0,1),]
```